# Вопрос по форматированию pug (jade) в html

Tags: html, jade, шаблонизаторы, pug

Имеется такая проблема при компиляции pug. Хоть она не так критична технически, но визуально довольно неприятна.

Вот такой код:

```
.block
    a(href="#" class="link")
```

Конвертируется в html так:

```
<div class="block"><a class="link" href="#"></a></div>
```

Собственно на этом примере отображены все 2 проблемы, о которых я хочу спросить:

1) код одной строкой идет. А нужно так:

```
<div class="block">
    <a class="link" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

2) В ссылке порядок атрибутов изменен. Мне нужно чтоб атрибут href стоял первым, а оно конвертирует так.

Помогите, кто разбирается в pug, почему pug так компилирует, возможно ли изменить это и как?
Спасибо.

Comment: Думаю сначала можно добавить флаг `--pretty`. [Документация](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-cli#options)

Comment: Насчет порядка атрибутов, *pug* всегда ставит класс на первую позицию, потому что это какая-то оптимизация ― смотри [здесь](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/1793)

Comment: Есть ли какой-то способ изменить порядок атрибутов? чтоб href стоял первым.

Comment: Последнюю ссылку открывали?

Comment: Можете понятнее рассказать? Открывал, но дело в том, что я не силен в подобных моментах и тем более если на иностранном языке...

Comment: Нельзя изменить порядок, class всегда будет на первом месте. Это сделано для того что бы оптимизировать gzip компиляцию. Также комьюнити придерживается следующего [codeguide](http://codeguide.co/#html-attribute-order). Можете уточнить зачем Вам нужен иммено такой порядок с `href` на первом месте?

Comment: Просто визуально привычнее. Всегда в html писал сначала href, а pug теперь наоборот делает.

Comment: Читай гайд выше